# How do I show algebraically that the period of the tangent function is $\pi$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

How do I show that the positive real number $p$ for which $\tan (x+p)=\tan (x)$ is equal to $\pi$? In essence how do I prove the period of the tangent function is $\pi$? 
Please bear in mind I am a pre-calculus student, thanks.

Comment: How did you define the tangent? What do you know about it (identities, things like that)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Use the identity $$\tan(\alpha + \beta)=\frac{\tan\alpha + \tan \beta}{1-\tan\alpha \tan\beta}$$

---

**Edit:**
In order to prove that $\pi$ is indeed the period, we need to show that $\tan(x+\pi)=\tan(x)$. Let's start from the LHS and get to the RHS using the identity. We let $\alpha = x$ and $\beta= \pi$, also remember that $\tan \pi =0$, so: $$\tan(x + \pi)=\frac{\tan x + \tan \pi}{1-\tan x \tan\pi} = \frac{\tan x + 0}{1-(\tan x)(0)} = \frac {\tan x}{1} = \tan x$$ Thus $\pi$ is the period. By the way if you start with the problem "$\tan (x + p) = \tan x$, find the period $p$" then you would have many different solutions, because $p=2\pi$ is also a period that satisfies the equation. Infact, any $n\pi$ works as a period where $n$ is a nonzero integer.

---

**Edit 2:** Let's try to find the period $p$ instead of proving that $\pi$ is a period. The method is similar. We know that if $p$ is the period, then $\tan(x+p)=\tan x$ which is the key fact here. So we want a $p$ that satisfies this: $$\tan(x + p)=\frac{\tan x + \tan p}{1-\tan x \tan p}=\tan x$$ Manipulating this expression gives: $$\tan x + \tan p=\tan x - \tan^2 x \tan p \implies \tan p(\tan^2 x +1)=0 \implies \tan p=0 \\ \implies p=n\pi$$ for $n= ... -3,-2,-1,1,2,3 \dots$

If you put $n=1$ you get $p=\pi$ which is what we proved earlier to be a period. Also, $n \neq 0$, because $p$ can't be zero due to the definition of a period.

Comment: I've substituted $0$ for $\alpha$ and I get $\tan (0+\beta)$ equals $\tan (\beta)$ after some simplifying but im unsure as to where to go from here..

Comment: I added an explanation for that. See the edit made to the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, my question is why did you start with this equation $\tan (x+\pi)$? It seems as if you already started with the knowledge you knew the period was pi

Comment: Well, that was my answer to your question *In essence how do I prove the period of the tangent function is $\pi$?*. However, to find the periods, see my edit.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

$$\tan(x+p)-\tan x=\frac{\sin(x+p)}{\cos(x+p)}-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\sin(x+p-x)}{\cos(x+p)\cos x}$$

We know, if $\sin p=0\implies p=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind how you've set this all up?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: $n$ cannot be *any integer* since zero is an integer and $p=0$ is not a period.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi, What is the definition of period?

Comment: Well according to what I understand, and this is my "intuitive" definition. Frankly, I'm not aware of the formal one. Mine is: if $f(x+p)=f(x)$ then $f$ is a periodic function with period $p \neq 0$.

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi, The smallest positive real number $p$

Comment: Actually I checked Wikipedia: [link](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function), it says $p$ is a non zero constant.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary for the period to be the smallest $p$. According to wiki, the "fundamental period" is the smallest $p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really nice and concise!

Answer (score 3):

The function
$$\tan t:={\sin t\over\cos t}$$
is on its domain the quotient of two functions with the property $f(t+\pi)\equiv-f(t)$. It follows that $\tan$ has period $\pi$.